# python: Constructor goes into infinite loop

Tags: python, inheritance

My purpose is to override some of the functions of 'First' class run-time for certain cases. So I want to derive a class from the original one. Here is the code snippet.

```python
class First(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "First"
        super(First, self).__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print "foo"

class Second(First):

    def __init__(self):
        print "second"
        super(Second, self).__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print "want to override this"

First = Second

o = First()
```

Why the constructor goes into infinite loop? What wrong thing am doing?

Comment: tag your programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python names are not looked up at compile time, name lookups happen when the code is executed.

The thing to watch out for is

```
First = Second
```

- Because of the assignment, `First()` will create an instance of `class Second`
- `Second.__init__()` will call `First.__init__()`.
- in `First.__init__()`, `First` will be looked up **by name** in the global context.
- Since you reassigned `First = Second`, the **name** `First` points to `class Second`. Which will get its `__init__()` called and that gives you your infinite recursion.

In short: Don't do this ...

Comment: instead of super() if I call parent constructor directly, it does not go into recursive loop.. however my purpose is to patch the original function runtime and not the class itself. Monkey patching kind of approach might help.

Comment: Helper tools for function/method wrapping and monkey patching are in `functools`, `functools.wraps` is your friend.